# Thick Japanese bracket symbols

Tags: brackets

Is there a way to create this type of thick japanese  bracket in the picture far right? I use it to enumerate a puzzle collection like this [number]. Just looking for a way to make it look like in some japanese book typesetting i have seen.[image]

Comment: These are Chinese fonts but not Japanese fonts. Also I advise you not to use them around numbers since in Chinese the thick bracket has their own uses and are not used in such way.

Answer (score 6):

In Unicode the characters are

U+3010 LEFT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET 【

U+3011 RIGHT BLACK LENTICULAR BRACKET 】

and are present in the vast majority of OpenType/TrueType fonts supporting Japanese.

Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`.

Answer (score 2):

You could design your own using `TikZ` and the `scalerel` package.

[image]

Two new commands `\ljp` and `\rjp` are defined that scale a `tikzpicture` to the size of a standard parenthesis. The commands take an optional argument that can be `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg`.

There are three global parameters to adjust the shape however you like: `\toplen` is the length of the top edge as a percentage of the height. It is set to `.25` in the above image. `inangle` is the angle that the curved portion deviates from vertical. It is set to `30` in the above image. A larger angle will make the symbol thinner. `loosen` controls the `looseness` of the curve. Lower value results in less curve.

For example, here is the same image with `\toplen` set to `.35` and `\inangle` set to `75`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,scalerel}

\newcommand{\toplen}{.25}
\newcommand{\inangle}{30}
\newcommand{\loosen}{1}

\newcommand{\ljp}[1][]{\scalerel*{\tikz{\fill (0,0)--(0,1)--(\toplen,1)to[bend right=\inangle, looseness=\loosen]++(0,-1)--cycle;}}{#1(}}
\newcommand{\rjp}[1][]{\scalerel*{\tikz[xscale=-1]{\fill (0,0)--(0,1)--(\toplen,1)to[bend right=\inangle, looseness=\loosen]++(0,-1)--cycle;}}{#1)}}

\begin{document}

\[
\ljp A+B\rjp(A+B)\quad
\ljp[\Big]\frac{A}{B}\rjp[\Big]\Big(\frac{A}{B}\Big)\quad
\ljp[\bigg]\frac{A}{B}\rjp[\bigg]\bigg(\frac{A}{B}\bigg)
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I change the thickness horizontally?

Comment: @john: I edited my response to give more control over the appearance.